# Why is the balance not getting updated after Deposit or Withdraw?

Tags: c++, c++11

I am a beginner in C++ and I come from a non-CS background. I was making this project of a Bank Management System using C++, but I am facing a problem. Whenever I am Depositing or withdrawing money, it is not getting updated when I do "2 Balance Enquiry". Can anyone help me understand why it is so and also How to fix it? I am new to this so please forgive me if this is a stupid question. Thanks

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

//***************  C U S T O M E R  ***************

class Customer {
    string fname, lname;
    long accno;
    float balance;
    static long count;

public:
    Customer() {}

    Customer(string fn, string ln, float b) {
        count++;
        fname = fn;
        lname = ln;
        balance = b;
        accno = count;
    }

    long getaccno() {
        return accno;
    }

    void greetnewcx() {
        cout << "Hello, " << fname << " " << lname << endl;
        cout << "Account Successfully Created. Account Number: " << getaccno();
        cout<<"\nBalance: Rs." << balance;
    }

    void deposit(float dep) {
        balance += dep;
        cout << "Successfully deposited\nNew Balance: Rs." << balance;
    }

    void greeting() {
        cout << "Hello, " << fname << " " << lname << endl;
    }

    void withdraw(float withdraw) {
        balance -= withdraw;
        cout << "Successfully withdrawn\nRemaining Balance: Rs." << balance;
    }

    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, Customer& c);   
};

long Customer::count = 0;

//***************  B A N K  ***************

class Bank {
    map<long, Customer> accounts;

public:
   Bank() {
      Customer account;
   }
   
   Customer open_account(string f, string l, float b);
   void show_allaccounts();
   void show_balance(long acno);
   void deposit(long acno);
   void withdraw(long acno);
   void removeacc(long acno);
};

//***************  M A I N  ***************

int main() {  
    Bank b;
    Customer cx;

    int choice;
    string fname, lname;
    long accountNumber;
    float balance;

    do {
        cout << "\n\n\tSelect one option below ";
        cout << "\n\t1 Open an Account";
        cout << "\n\t2 Balance Enquiry";
        cout << "\n\t3 Deposit";
        cout << "\n\t4 Withdrawal";
        cout << "\n\t5 Close an Account";
        cout << "\n\t6 Show All Accounts";
        cout << "\n\t7 Quit";
        cout << "\nEnter your choice: ";
        cin >> choice;

        switch (choice) {
        case 1:
            cout << "\nFirst Name: " << endl;
            cin >> fname;
            cout << "\nLast Name: " << endl;
            cin >> lname;
            cout << "Initial Balance: Rs." << endl;
            cin >> balance;

            cx = b.open_account(fname, lname, balance);
            
            break;

        case 2:
            cout << "Enter Account Number: ";
            cin >> accountNumber;
            b.show_balance(accountNumber);
            break;

        case 3:
            cout << "Enter Account Number: ";
            cin >> accountNumber;
            b.deposit(accountNumber);
            break;

        case 4:
            cout << "Enter Account Number: ";
            cin >> accountNumber;
            b.withdraw(accountNumber);
            break;

        case 5:
            cout << "Enter Account Number: ";
            cin >> accountNumber;
            b.removeacc(accountNumber);
            break;

        case 6:
            b.show_allaccounts();
            break;

        case 7:
            break;

        default:
            cout << "\nEnter corret choice";
            exit(0);
         
        }
    } while (choice != 7);


    
    return 0;
}

//***************  F U N C T I O N S  **************

Customer Bank::open_account(string f, string l, float b) {

    Customer cx(f, l, b);   //calling constructor of Class Customer
    
    accounts.insert(pair<long,Customer>(cx.getaccno(), cx));
    cx.greetnewcx();
    return cx; 

};

void Bank::show_balance(long acno) {
    map<long, Customer> ::iterator itr;
    itr = accounts.find(acno);

    cout << itr->second << endl;
}

void Bank::deposit(long acno) {
    map<long, Customer> ::iterator itr;
    itr = accounts.find(acno);
    auto cx = itr->second;
    cx.greeting();
    cout << "\nEnter the amount to deposit: Rs.";
    float d;
    cin >> d;
    cx.deposit(d);
}

void Bank::withdraw(long acno) {
    map<long, Customer> ::iterator itr;
    itr = accounts.find(acno);
    auto c = itr->second;
    c.greeting();
    cout << "\nEnter the amount to withdraw: Rs.";
    float d;
    cin >> d;
    c.withdraw(d);
}

void Bank::removeacc(long acno) {
    accounts.erase(acno);
    cout << "Account Deleted.";
}

void Bank::show_allaccounts() {
    map<long, Customer> ::iterator itr;
    for (itr = accounts.begin(); itr != accounts.end(); itr++) {
        cout <<"Account No. " <<itr->first<< endl;
        cout << itr->second<<endl;
    }
}

//***************  OPERATOR OVERLOADED F U N C T I O N S  **************

ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, Customer& c) {
    out << c.fname << " " << c.lname << endl;
    out << "Balance: Rs." << c.balance << endl << endl;
    return out;
}
```

Comment: What do you expect this to do? `Bank() { Customer account; }`

Answer (score 1):

```
        cx = b.open_account(fname, lname, balance);
```

This makes a *copy* of the `Customer`. You now have one `Customer` in `cx` and another one inside the map. You then modify the copy you stored in `cx` leaving the one inside the map untouched.

You do this elsewhere too:

```
Customer Bank::open_account(string f, string l, float b) {

    Customer cx(f, l, b);   //calling constructor of Class Customer

    accounts.insert(pair<long,Customer>(cx.getaccno(), cx));
    cx.greetnewcx();
    return cx; 

};
```

Here, you create a `Customer` in `cx`, but then you create another `Customer` inside the `accounts` structure (that's what `insert` does), then you return yet another `Customer` because `cx` goes out of scope. You only wanted to create *one* customer but you created three.

In sum, your code does this:

1. It creates a new `Customer` with `Customer cx(...`.
2. It puts a copy of that `Customer` in the map with `insert`.
3. It returns a copy of that `Customer` using `return`.
4. The calling code than initializes an existing `Customer` to the value of the returned copy with `cx = b.open_account...`.

You really only wanted one `Customer`, not four.